# What is the usage policy for Leaflet Maps?

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap

I would like to know the usage policy for Leaflet tiles maps. Leaflet is based on OSM, but the documentation is not clear both in Leaflet and in OSM about the usage policy. Thank you for your Help!

Answer (score 6):

Leaflet is a library. It doesn't provide any tiles at all. That means the policy depends on the tile server you are choosing. Each tile server has a different tile usage policy. The policy for OSM tiles can be found [here](https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/tiles/).

Answer (score 4):

Leaflet is only a library, is BSD licensed, you can use it everywhere, without warranty: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/LICENSE

For the OSM tile usage limits, you can find them here
https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/tiles/

Basically some rule of thumb I use is

- if you have a "small" application (< 100 visits per day), use it, no problem.
- if you have a "medium" app (< 1000 visits per day) consider using a tile cache server.
- if you hace a "large" app (> 1000 visits per day) use a tile cache server

See: [How to setup a tile cache server](http://jperelli.com.ar/post/2017/12/17/how-to-cache-openstreetmap-tiles/)